# Checking Hash if a Value is exists or not in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, matching

I have a hash as :

```
hsh = {"http://localhost:3000/sales?"=>[], "am"=>["Room Service", "Coffee Shop", "Business Center"]}
```

And I have another variable as **c.value**  contains "Room Service"

Now I want to check that if `Room Service` value is exist in hash or not, I used this but it shows an error.

```
if hsh.any? {|x| x[:am] == "#{c.value}" }
```

Error:

```
can't convert Symbol into Integer.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: The `am` key in your hash is a string, not a symbol.

Comment: It is related to ruby, you should do your homework first before asking questions. And if you are sure that key **:am** exists then why would you loop through the hash? You should directly use `hsh[:am].include? c.value`. It will return true if the array contains the value.

Comment: I am new user at Stackoverflow but, I wonder!, why people are always ready to downvote the questions? They are not as ready to solve the issues as they are ready to downvote. Its also a big issue here. grow up guyz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sould try

```
if hsh.any? { |key, value| value.include? c.value }
```

Comment: Now If I want to get all the values of "am" one by one, how to implement it?

Comment: Well, as `hsh` is a hash, you can simply retrieve values for the `"am"` key with `hsh["am"]`

Answer (score 1):

try `hsh.detect { |k,v| v.include? c.value }`

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the "am" key and check if it include your value.

```
hsh.fetch("am", []).include?(c.value)
```

This way even if you don't have an "am" key you will not get an error.

Also note that your key is a string.